# function returncolor in HTML, how to add a returncolor for no data?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question concerning a return value. Someone helped me generating certain colors for certain ranges. However, some polygons I created in the HTML do not have a value, nor do they exist in the database which is connected to the HTML. However, I want to place them on my map, but as no data (with a color). Having polygons which do not exist in the database linked to the HTML automatically gives them the color black, but I want to create white colors for these polygons. I can't find where the color black is generated in this code. I do have the fill color for all values lower then 1, but this does not give the color for Polygons who do not exist. Can I add a line for no data and give this the return color I want? If so, how? For instance, adding the line:

```
if (dados [i][1] = nodata {
return '#FFFFFF';
if (dados[i][1] < 1) { 
        return '#00FF00';
```

This example does not work, but maybe something similar which works?

```
var colort;
function returncolor (dados,name) {
 //
 for (var i=0;i<dados.length;++i){

  //console.log(i);
  //var row = dados[i];
  //console.log(i + row.toString());
  //var linha = row[0];
  //console.log(i + row.toString() + row[0] + name);
  if (dados[i][0] == name ){
   //console.log(i + row.toString() + row[0] + name + row[1]);
   //val = row[1];
   //*
   if (dados[i][1] < 1) { 
    return '#00FF00';
   }else if(dados[i][1]  < 101){
    return '#A9BCF5' ; 
   }else if (dados[i][1]  < 201){ 
    return '#5882FA';
}else if (dados[i][1]  < 301){ 
    return '#013ADF';
}else if (dados[i][1]  < 100000){ 
    return '#0B2161';
   }//*/
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a single variable to return the color instead of arbitrarily exiting the loop using `return`. This should allow you to set a default return value which will be used when:

```
dados[i][0] != name
typeof dados[i][1] !== 'number'
dados[i][1] >= 100000
```

Example:

```
function returncolor(dados, name) {
    var i,
        color = '#FFFFFF'; // default to white
    //
    for (i = 0; i < dados.length; i += 1) {
        if (dados[i][0] == name) {
            if (dados[i][1] < 1) {
                color = '#00FF00';
                break; // no longer returning immediately, use break to exit loop
            } else if (dados[i][1] < 101) {
                color = '#A9BCF5';
                break; // no longer returning immediately, use break to exit loop
            } else if (dados[i][1] < 201) {
                color = '#5882FA';
                break; // no longer returning immediately, use break to exit loop
            } else if (dados[i][1] < 301) {
                color = '#013ADF';
                break; // no longer returning immediately, use break to exit loop
            } else if (dados[i][1] < 100000) {
                color = '#0B2161';
                break; // no longer returning immediately, use break to exit loop
            }
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```